# provisioning profile name

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-provisioning

I have a new app, and create the profile for developing.

I get a weird mistake:

```
Provisioning profile 'vallabici' specifies the Application Identifier
'com.ingeniaSoluciones.Vallabici' which doesn't match the current setting
'com.ingeniaSoluciones.Vallabici'
```

It's the same. I tried cleaning the project, but it still doesnt work.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a glich. Its mostly occurs when you upgrade your xcode. How i solved it. I had close my project and delete current provisioning profile and downloaded it again. and added it to organizer and then start my project and cleaned it and voilla it run again.